# How do I attach a custom function to process org-mode babel shell output?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, hooks

I have a a function

```
(defun display-ansi-colors ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

that I got from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378271/how-do-i-display-ansi-color-codes-in-emacs-for-any-mode

I'd like to run it automatically after `org-babel-sh-evaluate` or `org-babel-execute:shell` to strip the ANSI color codes from the output and colorize the org-mode `#+RESULTS` block.

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe add it to the `org-babel-after-execute-hook` with appropriate precautions to apply it only to shell code blocks? Untested - and I don't know off the top of my head how to take those "appropriate precautions".

Comment: @Nick: yep, and the odds are that ANSI codes are unique enough that it wouldn't matter whether you applied to to _all_ code blocks.  But that somewhat offends my aesthetics :), and I'm not sure how to filter for just `org-babel-sh-evaluate` or `org-babel-execute:shell`

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this more or less works when put together in an org file:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results none
(require 'cl)
(defun org-redisplay-ansi-source-blocks ()
  "Refresh the display of ANSI text source blocks."
  (interactive)
  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'src-block
    (lambda (src)
      (when (equalp "ansi" (org-element-property :language src))
        (let ((begin (org-element-property :begin src))
              (end (org-element-property :end src)))
          (ansi-color-apply-on-region begin end))))))

(add-to-list 'org-babel-after-execute-hook #'org-redisplay-ansi-source-blocks)

(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages '((shell . t)))
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output verbatim drawer :wrap src ansi
echo "\e[33mTest text\e[0m"
echo Styles: '\e[3mitalic\e[0m' '\e[1mbold\e[0m' '\e[4munderline\e[0m' '\e[1m\e[3mbolditalics\e[0m'
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+BEGIN_src ansi
Test text
Styles: italic bold underline bolditalics
#+END_src
```

How it ends up looking like:

[image: screenshot]

One issue I don't know how to fix yet is when the file is saved, all the ANSI information is lost.